# performFiltering() sql exception while filtering android.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to filter SimpleCursorAdapter ListView But I am getting sql exception in filtering.
I am trying to find those contacts who's name start's with user's entered text.

```
 String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);


 adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                    return getDirectoryList(constraint);
                }
            });


 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changing now"+cs
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MyActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }
  });

   public Cursor getDirectoryList (CharSequence constraint)  {
            String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " display_name like %"+constraint.toString()+"%";
            return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);
        }
```

Here is exception

```
  An exception occured during performFiltering()!
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "display_name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT sort_key, photo_uri, send_to_voicemail, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, contacts_status_updates.status_label AS contact_status_label, pinned, display_name, phonebook_label_alt, phonebook_bucket, contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, in_default_directory, photo_id, custom_ringtone, _id, times_contacted, phonebook_label, display_name_alt, lookup, phonetic_name, last_time_contacted, contact_last_updated_timestamp, has_phone_number, in_visible_group, display_name_source, photo_file_id, is_user_profile, contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts, sort_key_alt, phonebook_bucket_alt, agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, starred, photo_thumb_uri, contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, agg_presence.chat_capability AS contact_chat_capability, phonetic_name_style, name_raw_contact_id FROM view_contacts LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (_id = agg_presence.presence_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id) WHERE ((1)) AND ((has_phone_number display_name like %ab%))
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
        at com.websmithing.gpstracker.GpsTrackerActivity.getDirectoryList(GpsTrackerActivity.java:189)
        at com.websmithing.gpstracker.GpsTrackerActivity$2.runQuery(GpsTrackerActivity.java:128)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CursorAdapter.java:395)
        at android.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:49)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: it has no sense: `String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " display_name like %"+constraint.toString()+"%";`

Comment: why are you adding `ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER`  to your selection

Comment: So how can i pass selection who has phone number and their names start with user's input? In short how can filter contacts?

Comment: Because i want to retrieve only those contacts who has phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " display_name like %"+constraint.toString()+"%";
```

use

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " and display_name like '%"+constraint.toString()+"%'";
```

this may solve the problem

Comment: But may be it will give all those results who does not have phone numbers like it will give email-id's. Am i right?

Comment: check out my edited answer instead of phone_number you can enter your entity name

Comment: By the way i tried this but still i am getting this  sql exception      (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id) WHERE ((1)) AND ((display_name like %abc%))

Comment: did you add phone_number =

Comment: After your update getting sqlException  near% ((phone_number=has_phone_number and display_name like %a%

Comment: i am sorry forgot to add + now it is ok use this `"phone_number=" + `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79340/discussion-between-vishwajit-palankar-and-neooo).